# How to scroll last item on RecyclerView to the top position?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I apologize beforehand, I do not have any code examples as I am completely in the dark for the solution to my problem. I want to know, how can I scroll the last item of a list to the top position of the recycler view?

By default, if all items are displaying, and scrolling is not necessary, then you can no longer scroll to see more items. The conflict with this is that I am updating information on a separate view based upon the top most item.

Any ideas for this? The only thing I could think of was to add arbitrary, fake empty data so that I can continue scrolling. Thanks in advance

UPDATE: The best alternative solution other than dummy data is to add padding to the RecyclerView. If I add paddingBottom, you do not see the empty space until you scroll to the last item. But the padding has to be precise to force the last item to the top position. So even this is flawed.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/rv_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
```

Comment: Maybe some code could help !

Comment: There is nothing to do. I am not asking for how to setup a recyclerview. I am asking if there is an attribute that does what I described, such as setStackFromEnd in LayoutManager or setNestedScrolling on the recyclerview level. Any attribute that is known that will do this, or do I have to create a custom RecyclerView or come up with some hack. That is really the question.

Comment: Maybe this : //Scroll item 2 to 20 pixels from the top
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);

Comment: Yes, but this is before. This does not apply after. After the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. This takes you to a specific position upfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get this to work. First I measure the size of the item in the adapter in onBindViewHolder

```
holder.llWrapper.measure(0,0);
```

I getMeasuredHeight() from that and pass that back from my Adapter to my Fragment. I then measure the recycler view height. I subtract the height of the recyclerview and the item and the remainder is the amount of padding I need to set bottom to the recyclerview

```
rv.setPadding(0,0,0,padding);
```

This is the best I can come up with. Cheers!

Comment: Did we get a better solution than this? There must be some code in the recyclerview which i can override i think